# Firebase stop listening for child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

Is it possible that i can stop the childeventlistener?
Because im receiving my marker lat and long from the server and when im trying to add one more the app crashes because it sais 
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
So now i want to disable the the listener when im sending the information to the server and receiving the markers again. I know the functions .removeeventlistener but i dont know how to use it the right way. Does someone got an answer for me? 
Cheers!

Comment: If you attached a listener with `addChildEventListener()`, you can remove it with [`removeEventListener()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query). I'm pretty sure I answered with an example recently, so I'll find (and mark as) a duplicate. If you need more help, share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it contains all kinds of hints of why this is useful and how to improve your chances of getting good help here on StackOverflow).

Comment: Hello Frank, yes i have already red this post. But i dont know what ref is. Can u give me an example please? That would save my day.

Comment: `ref` is a common name for a `FirebaseDatabase` reference. We use it regularly throughout the Firebase documentation, e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events. Again: if you're having problems making your code work, share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Code > words that describe code.

Comment: Im trying this final 
DatabaseReference getlats = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MapMitglieder");
getlats.addChildEventListener
Code code code

Button.setOnClickListener
getlats.removeEventListener((ChildEventListener) getlats);

Error: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the *listener* and pass that into `removeEventListener()`. Study the code in the dupe I linked carefully.